# Haskell: Traversal on a Map

Tags: dictionary, haskell, traversal

I'm looking for a function with this signature:

```
chainTraversal :: k -> (k -> a -> Maybe (k, b)) -> Map k a -> Map k b
```

You give it an initial key to start at, a function and a map.

It will extract the element at the position `k` in the Map, and feed that element to the function. Based on this, the function will return another key to look at next.

It's some mix between a filter and a traversal, with the elements themselves giving the next position to open. The result is the list of elements that has been traversed. It can be shorter than the original map.

Edit: taking into account a comment.

Comment: If it does not each every key, it can not map each key, hence there are still tuples with `a` as value. So in that case perhaps the signature should be `myTraversal :: k -> (k -> a -> (k, a)) -> Map k a -> Map k a`?

Comment: Yes it does not necessarily reach every key. I edited the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since all the lookups are done in the original Map:

```
foo :: k -> (k -> a -> Maybe (k, b)) -> Map k a -> Map k b
foo k f m = fromList $ unfoldr g k
  where
  g k = (\(k', b) -> (k', (k, b)))    -- k ? k' ? you decide
           <$> (f' k =<< (m `at` k))
  f' k (k', a) = f k a          -- or:   f k' a ? you decide
```

or something like that.

You'll have to implement the `at` function in terms of one of the `lookupNN` functions of your choosing.

It's not a filter since it must stop on the first `Nothing` produced by `f`.

Comment: Thanks, I think `unfoldr` is the function I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

There is no existing function with that signature and behavior. You'll have to write it yourself.